# Change the color of an icon within a button within a UIBarButton (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIToolbar at the with a UIBarButton containing a button containing an image (the image changes when clicked, so I apparently had to do it that way according to my research).

Although the image itself is white and is a png, it's displaying as black (I want it white).  I've set the tint color on the Bar Button Item to white, the text color on the Button to white, and  included 
`button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)` 
in my ViewDidLoad.  It's still black.  It should always be white, so I don't care whether I do this programmatically or through the InterfaceBuilder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to load image in `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` render mode:

Objective-C

```
UIImage *toolbarButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:toolbarButtonImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(someAction)];
```

Swift:

```
let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "SomeImage")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: buttonImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "someAction:")
```